# What does this Inside of a mango mean?

Tags: mango

Ok to consume? Of not how to identify this issue before buying?
What causes this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This may be a better fit for the culinary site: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MackM if it’s about food safety, yes. If it’s about causes, it’s perfectly fine here. (I happen to be a mod on both sides, which is occasionally handy.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the seeds have not formed properly.  Perhaps the flowers were not pollinated.

Since mangoes are self-pollinated, perhaps there is a lack of bees in your area.